# While I live, I seldom face the ground!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix lies far above the sky 
>   My Infix is a movement to be found 
>   My suffix is not so high 
>   While I live, I seldom face the ground!

Who am I?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are a:

> Sunflower

My prefix lies far above the sky

> Sun - a good distance up above

My Infix is a movement to be found

> Flow - a movement, not sure if "to be found" indicates something further

My suffix is not so high

> "Lower"

While I live, I seldom face the ground!

> Sunflowers are known to face the sky, in particular the sun. At least while they are alive.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are a:

> Rainbow

My prefix lies far above the sky

> Rain:  Rain comes from clouds, and some clouds (like Cumulus Clouds) can appear to be sitting right on top of the sky, or even higher.

My Infix is a movement to be found

> In:  As in "to go 'into' something."

My suffix is not so high

> Bow:  To lower one's torso, as in "to take a bow."

While I live, I seldom face the ground!

> Rainbows are often located at the horizon, facing the opposite horizon, in a direction roughly parallel to the ground.  (Some, like waterfall rainbows, *can* face the ground, but as for across-the-sky rainbows, not so much.)

Comment: A great alternative, if only if the rain was above the sky! :)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac:  Thanks, Ébe Isaac!  But can't rain be above the sky?  After all, the sky's limit is somewhat undefined.  (And "sky" isn't necessarily the same as "atmosphere"...)